# Which was the "wow" scene that Sanderson was talking about?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, brandon-sanderson

The following is summarised from an [interview with Brandon Sanderson](http://www.theoryland.com/intvmain.php?i=527#10) in 2010:

> Q: Were there parts that you were like, just wow, this is just really weird having to write this?
>
> A: The other scene has not come up yet so I can't tell you what it is. It was just a "wow." It was kind of that, "How did I miss that?" in part, and also a "I really need to make this really work really well." And anyway, I can tell you about that next year.

Does anybody know which scene Sanderson was talking about?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe he is referring to Verin's final scene.

> Verin’s Black Ajah identity was the most shocking revelation that Brandon learned while going through Jordan’s notes on the series.

This quote was taken from [Brandon Sanderson’s Wheel of Time Answers From #TorChat](http://www.tor.com/blogs/2013/01/brandon-sandersons-wheel-of-time-answers-from-torchat).

EDIT: I believe my original answer is wrong. When I answered it, I was sure that scene happened on Towers of Midnight, but recently I re-read the final books and found out this scene is actually near the ending of The Gathering Storm, which came out in 2009, so Sanderson could have talked about it freely in that 2010 interview.

If I had to guess which scene he was really talking about, which has to be a scene from Towers of Midnight, I would guess it was

> Aviendha experiencing the destruction of the Aiel in Rhuidean.

Comment: Thank you. I guess that caught _me_ completely unawares  too.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Verin lied at the The Great Hunt, but no one realized it.

Comment: Any source? Any evidence for this?

Comment: http://www.encyclopaedia-wot.org/ THat is the best site. IT was at the end. They didn't think she was lying. I can't remember exactly what it was. This was my wow moment with Verin also. Oh, she was lying at the end of book 2.

Comment: She turns up and joins Rand and Co when they hunt Fain. She says something like "Moiraine sent me". Later, Rand or somebody confronts Moiraine and says something like "You sent Verin to controll us..." and she goes "No I did not". Ergo Verin lied.